# SQL command to Retrieve data where one column is null

Tags: sql

I have these table

```
Item
+-------+--------+
| ID    | Name   |
+-------+--------+
| 1     | itemA  |
+-------+--------+

Sales
+-------+--------+-------------+-----+
| ID    | ItemID | WarehouseID | ... |
+-------+--------+-------------+-----+
| ABC   | 1      | null        | ... |
+-------+--------+-------------+-----+
ItemID = FK of Item(ID)
WarehouseID = FK of Warehouse(ID)

Warehouse
+--------+----------+------+-------+
| ID     | ItemID   | Qty  | Price |
+--------+----------+------+-------+
| 1      | 1        | 10   | 5.00  |
+--------+----------+------+-------+
ItemID = FK of Item(ID)

**Expected Results:**
+--------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------+
| ItemID | ItemName | SalesID        | WarehouseID | Qty  | Price |
+--------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------+
| 1      | itemA    | ABC            | null        | null | null  |
+--------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Its null because the "WarehouseID" in the Sales is null.

How can i do these.. I tried but the results has no rows returned due to null value.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried?

Comment: The real case is close to this, but more complex with 4 tables involved. And for some reason I can't published it to public. Btw, I use Oracle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `INNER JOIN` + `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for the `WarehouseId`:

```
SELECT item.ID as ItemID, item.Name as ItemName,
       sales.Id as SalesID,
       sales.WarehouseID,
       wh.Qty, wh.Price
FROM Item 
INNER JOIN Sales
    ON item.ID = sales.ItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Warehouse wh
    ON sales.WarehouseID = wh.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Eh, something like that?

```
select i.ID as ItemID,
       i.Name as ItemName,
       s.ID as SalesID,
       w.ID as WarehouseID,
       w.Qty as Qty,
       w.Price as Price    
  from (Item i join Sales s 
          on i.Id = s.ItemID) left join
        WareHouse w on w.ItemId = i.ID and w.SalesID = s.ID
```

*inner join* between `Sales` and `Item` and *outer join* (*left* in the query) to `WareHouse`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT COALESCE(i.ItemId,NULL),COALESCE(i.ItemName,NULL)        
s.SalesID,COALESCE(w.WarehouseID,NULl),
COALESCE(w.Qty,NULL),COALESCE(w.Price,NULL)
FROM Sales s 
LEFT JOIM Item i On s.ItemID = i.ItemID 
LEFT JOIN Warehouse w ON s.WarehouseID =w.WarehouseID
```

Comment: because it retuns with value null if there is no WarehouseID matches from table Warehouse

Comment: The point of `COALESCE` is to return a different value if it is `NULL`.  You're effectively doing a computation that says "Return the value you actually got, unless you're `NULL`.  If you're `NULL`, return `NULL` instead."  It's a pointless operation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what database, but read about `outer join`. It's common in all sql'a engines

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Dave if question author show YOUR CODE at first (maybe not totally correct), then I agree :)  In polish we say "give to someone a fish or a fishing rod".